# Calling a PHP function on button click?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a html button which has an onclick method. The function which is ran onclick has a php function in but is called in JS, like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Test() {
      <?php add_post_meta($post->ID, '_my_meta_key', true); ?> 
    }
</script>
<button onclick="Test()"></button>
```

The page this code is on is a wordpress admin page. When the page loads, the php function is ran anyway instead of waiting for the button click event. Is there a way to stop this from happening and only fire once the button is clicked.

Comment: It is not possible. You need Ajax for this.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a simple way to do something like this in Ajax? It's just that I don't know it that well.

Comment: You might want to read [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: Thank you, will give it a read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot directly call a **php function using a button click**.But you can call **Js functions on button click event**.
And then you can **implement Ajax** to call php functions.

You are using **wordpress** so you can use **wp functions or custom coding** to achieve this.

**Php is server-side scripting language**.
Which will run only on server.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use AJAX.
You can learn some useful things on w3school:
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/